# glBindAttribLocation index 0

Tags: opengl

When I try to bind an attribute to an index of 0, the shader program fails at linking and the only information the infolog gives is:

> Vertex shader(s) failed to link, Fragment shader(s) linked.

According the the opengl docs

> This command makes it possible for vertex shaders to use descriptive names for attribute variables rather than generic variables that are numbered from 0 to GL_MAX_VERTEX_ATTRIBS -1.

So binding an attribute to index 0 should work. Though it is not very important, I am curious as to why I cannot bind an attribute to index 0. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Are you calling `glBindAttribLocation` _before_ or _after_ attaching the vertex shader to the program object? Also, have you checked `glGetError` immediately after `glBindAttribLocation`?

Comment: I am calling it after. glGetError returns no error. glBindAttribLocation works for other indices. (edit: after attaching, before linking)

Comment: Hmm sounds like it should work :(

Comment: I tried on another computer with a nVidia graphics card. Same result. It might be something with my shader. If its not and inconvenience for you, you could try yourself and see if you get the same result.

Comment: The only reason why it _could_ fail _without an error_ would be if none of the bindings referring to this index is used at all in the shader. Though in this case it would not work otherwise either. If you used a reserved name or such, there would be an error. I've seen binding attribute locations fail if you do so before binding the vertex shader (despite the spec explicitly allowing it), but that doesn't apply for you. Aliasing is also explicitly allowed, so the reason can't be that some other name is bound already... so... really no clue why it does not work.

Comment: I found the problem(this was causing other problems): in my vertex shader I had switched from using gl_Vertex to using my own attribute, "vertex", but at one place in my shader I had forgotten to change the variable name, and since gl_Vertex uses the 0 index...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting OP commentary, because it saved me:

> I found the problem(this was causing other problems): in my vertex shader I had switched from using gl_Vertex to using my own attribute, "vertex", but at one place in my shader I had forgotten to change the variable name, and since gl_Vertex uses the 0 index...

Comment: Note: `gl_Vertex` does *not* use attribute 0. The generic vertex attributes are not allowed to alias with the built-in ones; the specification is *very* clear about this. Not that that ever stopped NVIDIA, who *insists* on breaking the spec in this way. You can't use attribute 0 and `gl_Vertex` at the same time because they're both provoking attributes. So you have to pick one.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I don't understand what you mean. Attribute 0 is a special attribute that triggers the run of the vertex shader when set, and if you use gl_Vertex inside the shader, gl_Vertex will get the value you set to attribute index 0. That just makes sense, considering you need to call `glVertex*()` after you set other attributes when using `glBegin()` and `glEnd()` to draw.

Comment: The fact that what you described works *on your machine* does not mean that it *should* work. The OpenGL specification is quite clear on this. `glVertexAttrib(0, ...)` and `glVertex(...)` are *different*. They both provoke the execution of a vertex, but `glVertexAttrib(0, ...)` should never feed `gl_Vertex` in a vertex shader. **Ever.** NVIDIA's drivers do it, but that doesn't mean that they are right. That is a bug, one that NVIDIA has not fixed, and there is every indication that they will not fix it. They even consider this aliasing a feature, despite the spec forbidding it.